# Copying an ostream to a std::string

Tags: c++

I've a program that used to run as a commandline, hence has lots of `couts` in it. I was wondering if there was a way of creating an `ostream` object in the class that calls this program and initialize that programs constructor with something like

```
Import(ostream & text_out= std::cout):out(text_out)
```

and replace all my calls to `cout` with out, thereby switching where the output goes.

At the end of each function call, I could then extract the `ostream` object to a string, and send it to my MFC object.

This would mean my base code would be good if called either as a commandline or an MFC program, if I could get it to work. This could be me thinking along the wrong track, but I'm curious to see if this is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ostringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
std::ostream &os = oss;
os << "Hello" << endl;

std::string str = oss.str(); // str == "Hello\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are looking for [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).